# sql condition to display record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

tbl_users

```
u_id | u_type | u_first_name
 1      U        I_am_user
 2      E        I_am_emp   
 3      E        I_am_emp2
```

tbl_order

```
o_id | u_id | e_id | o_status | pay_status
  1     1       0    pending    Unpaid
  2     1       2    pick       Paid
  3     1       0    pending    Unpaid
  4     1       3    Pick       paid
```

I tried this query to show user and emp name

```
SELECT o.*, a.u_first_name as user, b.u_first_name as emp
  FROM `tbl_order` AS o
       LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS a ON a.u_id = o.u_id 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS b ON b.u_id = o.e_id

o_id | u_id | e_id |  user |  emp | pay_staus
```

How would we give condition(order by or other 1) to display unpaid (`pay_status`) record first 
then `e_id=0` record then rest all?

Comment: Can't you do `ORDER BY pay_status DESC`?

Comment: I tried but but how we will give next condition ?
unpaid 
e_id=0

Comment: did you mean order by 1,2,3 etc...

Comment: output is like 
first show all unpaid records 
after that (in same output) when all unpaid is over records with e_id=0
after that rest of all

Comment: could you please post your desired result set

Comment: e_id=0 mean that order don't have employee !

Comment: @Anu I updated the answer. Ans also see [`How do comment @replies work?`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query from `WHERE` clause should be like this:

```
WHERE e_id = 0 OR pay_status = 'Unpaid'
ORDER BY pay_status DESC;
```

So your whole query should be like this:

```
SELECT o.*, a.u_first_name as user, b.u_first_name as emp
  FROM `tbl_order` AS o
       LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS a ON a.u_id = o.u_id 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS b ON b.u_id = o.e_id
  WHERE e_id = 0 OR pay_status = 'Unpaid'
  ORDER BY pay_status DESC;
```

**EDIT:** ([From OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471034/sql-condition-to-display-record#comment16777075_12471764))

If you want to show all records but in specific order, You just need to use [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) clause like this:

```
ORDER BY pay_status DESC, e_id ASC;
```

Comment: how we avoid "where" condition....
because it show only e_id=0
the output is like 
1) all records **unpaid** 
2) when all unpaid record over show **e_id=0**
3) when all e_id=0 record over show **rest** all

Comment: @Anu As you are not replying we can not help you more.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from(
SELECT o.*, a.u_first_name as user, b.u_first_name as emp, 0 as rnk 
FROM `tbl_order` AS o
LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS a ON a.u_id = o.u_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS b ON b.u_id = o.e_id
where pay_status='Unpaid'    
union all
SELECT o.*, a.u_first_name as user, b.u_first_name as emp, 1 as rnk 
FROM `tbl_order` AS o
LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS a ON a.u_id = o.u_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS b ON b.u_id = o.e_id
where pay_status!='Unpaid' and    e_id=0
union all
SELECT o.*, a.u_first_name as user, b.u_first_name as emp, 2 as rnk 
FROM `tbl_order` AS o
LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS a ON a.u_id = o.u_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS b ON b.u_id = o.e_id
where pay_status!='Unpaid' and    e_id!=0)a
order by rnk
```

Comment: SELECT o.*, a.u_first_name as user, b.u_first_name as emp
  FROM `tbl_order` AS o
       LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS a ON a.u_id = o.u_id 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS b ON b.u_id = o.e_id                               Does this query return anything?